# In SSIS, how to ignore Truncation errors in XML source?

Tags: xml, error-handling, ssis, truncation

I have a package that contains a data flow. In the data flow, I read from XML file using XML source. I want SSIS to ignore any failure caused by data truncation. I thought that this task is simple:

1) double-click on the XML source

2) go to the Error output tab

3) select a column

4) select "Ignore Failure" in the drop-down list that corresponds to the "Truncation".

5) Click OK

However, after doing these steps and then re-opining the XML source, I find that the value I selected has been lost and the column has retained its original value in the corresponding drop-down list.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: That's certainly not supposed to happen. Have you tried closing and reopening the package? Also is it possible the package is read-only?

Comment: No it's not read-only. I tried closing it and reopeing it but this didn't work. I have a feeling that it gets the new value but it just doesn't show it. I tried changing the value to "Redirect row" and then clicked OK. It showed a warning on the XML source saying "the rows sent to error output will be lost ..." and then I changed the value again to "Ignore failure" and clicked OK so the warning disappeared (which means it took the new value) but when I open it again to check if it took it I still see the original value "Fail component".

Comment: Note: even when I changed it to "Redirect row" it didn't show the value. It always show the same value "Fail component"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I was having the same problem and thought I would share what I found.  You have to use the Advanced Editor to set the truncation action.

1. Right-click the XML Source and select 'Show Advanced Editor...'
2. Go to the 'Input and Output Properties' tab
3. Expand the output that contains the column to ignore truncation
4. Expand 'Output Columns'
5. Under 'Common Properties' set 'TruncationRowDisposition' to 'RD_IgnoreFailure'